# 301 redirect issue using php code

Tags: php, redirect

I have this code that is written for page redirect and to generate 301 for proper SEO

```
  if(preg_match("/[index.php]$/", $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])) {

     $url = "http://" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . preg_replace("/(index.php)$/", "", $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
     $sapi = php_sapi_name();
     if(PHP_VERSION >= '4.3.0') {
        header("Location: $url", 0, 301);
     }
     else if($sapi == 'cgi' OR $sapi == 'cgi-fcgi') {
        header("Location: $url");

        header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently');
     }
     else {
        header("Location: $url");
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
     }
  }



http://www.dsmla.com returns a 200 (OK) response. 
http://dsmla.com returns a 200 (OK) response.
http://www.dsmla.com/index.php returns a 301 (permanent) redirect
http://dsmla.com/index.php returns a 301 (permanent) redirect
```

my code works fine for 2 urls but I want that it should only show 200 for only 1 link

Comment: Not the problem, but `preg_match("/[index.php]$/", $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])` doesn't do what I think you expect it does. using square brackets makes it a character class meaning any of the characters between the square brakets. So you are matching any ONE of `i, n, d, e, x, ., p, h, p` characters followed by the end of the string.

Comment: i didn't got your words can you explain it ? thanks

Comment: When you have a regex pattern, the square brackets `[ and ]` mean that any of the characters inside the square brackets can match. For example, if you have `[ABC]` that means a single character can be either `A`, `B` or `C`. It doesn't mean the string `ABC`. Your pattern means that any uri that ends with any of the letters `i`, `n`, `d`, `e`, `x`, `p`, `h` or `p` will redirect.

Comment: thanks , so how should  i write this ? can you tell me

Comment: just remove the square brackets and escape the dot. so `"/index.php$/"`

Comment: Like I said though, that is not the problem (or at least I didn't think so), it was just wrong.

Comment: can you give an example its not working :(